# google app script - authenticate website for accessing its data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a sidebar with the appscript. People who use this sidebar, are already users of my website abc.com. When he opens sidebar, I need to show him some content from my main website accessible only to his account. Lets say his profile in my website should be filled in the sidebar. For that, I need to authenticate that 'CALL TO SERVER' somehow so that I can send his data. In appscript, getActiveUser().getEmail() (or related) returns email, so we can fetch that persons data, but no authentication is done like this as anyone can send his email. Can you tell me the best way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service#serving_json_from_scripts) to GAS (as REST web-service), which will respond according to the parameter (for example you can send username to server and get reply)

```js
doGet(e){
    var user = e.parameter.username;
    var reply = getReplyFor(user); //get some reply for concrete user
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(reply).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I hope this helps

*sorry for bad english =)*